# Advise on how to work with multiple OrderedDict instances distributed across different files

Tags: for-loop, merge, openpyxl, glob, ordereddictionary

I want to create a script that processes files in a folder based on their names:.

- There are 2 types of files: (*alpha & beta*)
- All of the *alpha files* require the same manipulation (concatenation, filling blank cells, addition of a new column...)
- All of the *beta files* require the same manipulation (concatenation, filling blank cells, storage of certain variable...)
- Eventually, I'll need to merge *alpha files* with their corresponding *beta files* using a left merge.

### My questions

1. What's the best way to proceed with this task?
2. Can we handle all alpha files simultaneously?
3. Do we need to merge alpha files into one and beta files into another for further processing?

```py
# IMPORT MODULES

import openpyxl as op
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import os
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import glob


# MY FOLDER PATH

my_folder_path = r'C:\Users\machukovich\Desktop\working_folder'
list_of_files = os.listdir(my_folder_path)

print('This folder contains {len_folder} file(s): \n'.format(len_folder=len(list_of_files)))
for file_name in list_of_files:
    print(file_name)
    
# DEFINING THE ALPHA FILES

alpha_files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Edu\Desktop\working_folder\*_alpha.xlsx')
for file_name in alpha_files:
    print(file_name)
    
# DEFINING THE BETA FILES

beta_files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Edu\Desktop\working_folder\*_beta.xlsx')
for file_name in beta_files:
    print(file_name)
    
# FROM HERE IDK HOW TO CONTINUE ( THIS OPTION THROWS ERROR )


dfs_alpha = pd.read_excel(alpha_files, sheet_name=None, skiprows=3)
```

For more clarity, the output for my folder is the following:

```html
This folder contains 4 file(s): 

first_file_alpha.xlsx
first_file_beta.xlsx
second_file_alpha.xlsx
second_file_beta.xlsx
```

Comment: You do have the the last comment in the code  "# FROM HERE IDK HOW TO CONTINUE ( THIS OPTION THROWS ERROR )" where you then try to open a List of files. Pandas read_excel does not accept a List as the io. You can certainly read each xlsx file into a dataframe and manipulate the data in the dataframes. You can also combine the dataframes into one, however no idea if this is advantageous for what you need or not.

Comment: The alpha and beta files are .xlsx which I would like to read as OrderedDict. I would like to know if there is any method to apply certain manipulation to all of the alpha files. Can you read them simultaneously? Or you first need to merge them all into a single file?

Comment: You can manipulate the alpha files is all sorts of ways as either Dataframes or Excel data. *Can you read them simultaneously?* Read the alpha files into dataframes simultaneously?  pandas.read_excel accepts a single input type file or object. If you want them to be one dataframe it may be easier to read as separate dataframes and then join together but be aware of tables of different sizes may need adjustment.